# How to make my PostGIS vector layer in QGIS visible?

Tags: qgis, vector, postgis-2.0

I have loaded a shp file (simple polygon with one entry) into PostgreSQL 9.3 (with extention PostGIS v2.1.3).  I now want to load this layer into QGIS (v2.2.0 Valmeira) via the "load Postgis layer) command.  The connection is OK and the layer is transfered to QGIS without a problem.  I can see the table attributes in QGIS and the "Zoomin to the layer" fct works (the function zooms in with the correct center point and scale), but the layer is invisible!  Regardless of the symbology attributes that I use, I cannot see the layer.

I have also made a view of the table and loaded it into QGIS (specifying my coord syst - 4269 - and a int4 primary key) and I have the same problem.  Any idea of what the problem is?

Comment: Have you spatially enabled your DB, e.g. SELECT postgis_full_version(); ?

Comment: Yes, my postgresql DB has the postgis extension enabled.  The "Select postgis_full_version()" query returns "POSTGIS=2.1.3R12547 ..."

Comment: How did you load the shp into the DB?

Answer (score 1):

I've not got a straight answer for you but some thoughts - apologies if they're too obvious.

When you right click on the layer name and select the "Show Feature Count" box does it return the number you expected?

When you click on the layer in the Add PostGIS Layer screen, does the geometry column, data type, SRID projection and spatial type (Point, Linestring, etc) match what you expect?

If you click on the "!" messages button in the very bottom right of the QGIS screen does it show any unexpected errors relating to the layer?

Apologies if this is too obvious but is the Render box at the bottom of the screen checked?

Comment: The "Show Feature Count" is equal to "1" as expected.  The layer information (geometry column = geom, datatype = geometry, SRID = 4269 and spatial type = polygon) are OK.  No errors in the log messages.  And the "Render" box is checked!